# SQL -- temporarily snapshotting/archiving a query across Flask pages

Tags: python, sql, flask

I want to temporarily save information from one query across multiple flask routes.

Basically, I have a function solely for queries. I use a query to fetch a random id. Using this id, I gather all other information needed for this instance. It is then used in route1 (I call it here through a dictionary). The user inputs something and then all of the info is transferred to route2 using "url_for".

The program is messing up because instead of using the same id for both routes, route2 is querying again and using a different set of information based on a different id. I want the id to stay the same for both routes. I want it to change everytime route1 is refreshed or visited, but otherwise stay the same.

Let me know any thoughts or ideas!

```py
def get_db():
    random_id = db.execute("SELECT id FROM list ORDER BY RANDOM() LIMIT 1").fetchone()[0]

    score = query to select score using {random_id}
    image = quesry to select score using {random_id}
    info = {
    'random_id': random_id,
    'image': image,
    'score': score
    }
    return info

@app.route('route1')
data=det_db():
def functionA():
uses data.get() to call information from query in dictionary 
return redirect(url_for('fucntionB', random_id=random_id, image=image, score=score))

@app.route('route2')
def functionB():
info=request.args
random_id=info.get('random_id')
image=info.get('image')
score=info.get('score')
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked into local storage? Perhaps you could store the id in local storage when route1 is hit, and then access it when route2 is hit.

```
<script>
localstorage.setItem('name', 'value')
</script>

<script>
var item = localStorage.getItem('name');
</script>
```

These two scripts will allow you to store and retrieve from local storage.